# Android login via Phone in Firebase causes conflict with Cloud Console

Tags: android, firebase, sha1, google-cloud-console

The Firebase documentation states that to enable Phone login using Firebase, the SHA1 of the app needs to be added into the firebase console.
I cannot do that because my apps's SHA1 + package name combo already exists in a project in Google Cloud Console.

[image: Error seen when adding a SHA1 that exists in Cloud Console Project]
I had a similar issue when enabling Google Sign in the app.
I got around the error by whitelisting the Oauth clientID that was associated with this SHA1+package name by entering it into firbase

[image: Whitelist the Oauth client ID for Google Sign in]
Is there a way to whitelist the SHA1+packagename or the Oauth Client ID to enable Phone sign in?
I have found no way to do this. Google Sign In/Email Sign In works in my app but not phone.
This is a big issue that Firebase needs to resolve!
Anybody encounter this? How did you work around the issue?
Please note I cannot delete the Google Cloud console project or remove the SHA1+package name from cloud console. I need it there because I have Oauth client IDs that have been created there that cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here for anybody else who might run into a similar issue.
Turns out there is no way to enable Phone Login if the packagename+SHA1 exists in google cloud console.
Either change the package name or remove the Oauth Client Id that uses the packagename+SHA1 combination from Cloud Console.

[Link to the firebase forums where I asked this same question:](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/HzNr-aDweBY/m/PwhdGhPmAwAJ)